# What is this panel/console seen in Eighty Six?

Tags: 86-eighty-six

In *Eighty Six*, these console windows are shown.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do we have any names for the above console windows? Or was it just made up?

Comment: They are just some fancy military control room consoles.